# GAE MySQL Java Unit Testing - Computer Crashes all the time

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, hard-drive, easyphp

I have about 600 unit tests for my application.
The application uses Google Could SQL but MySQL for local and unit testing

Each time that I run the unit test my computer crashes (Freeze) about the middle.
I can see that the writes on the hard drive are really high as well.

I use EasyPHP for the MySQL Database, OS Windows 8, and GAE is in Java.
(8gb of ram) I tried to set the settings to this before launching the unit test suite:

```
set tmp_table_size = 16777216 * 8;
set max_heap_table_size = 16777216 * 8;
set global key_buffer_size = 8388608*100;
```

Let me know if you need more info.

(As my application is growing this problem become unmanageable)

Comment: It'd be nice to know what you've actually tried to debug.  Could be a bug in your test, a bug in your code (not very likely though), not enough RAM, faulty hardware of some sort (CPU, RAM, disk), etc.

Comment: i edited my question with those info. Looks like the unit test suite is going really fast at the beginning than more and more slow then it crashes. The number of connection is not growing much as well. Is definitely a database/hard drive problem resulting of testing